# Getting EREQUEST error: Incorrect syntax near '{'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sql-server-express, insert-update

I have integrated SQL Server Express into my ReactJS website. I am able to retrieve data from the database table, but when I try inserting data from my website to the database, I get an error with the following message:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tl4AF.jpg)

I am using `mssql` version 3.0 and SQL Server Management Studio 2019. I have tried installing the latest `mssql`, but the error persists. Is it possible that there is a setting issue inside the database studio?